# Filter Array with Multiple Changing Categories

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, filter

I'm trying to filter an array filled with JSON objects pulled by the `SHOPIFY API` for blog posts by their location and age range metafields.
I'm able to successfully filter each one separately but cannot figure out how to combine the two into one function. The filters on the front-end are the following:

```
<div class="row">
  <select class="select">
    <option value="">–Select Location–</option>
    <option value="Uptown Location">Uptown Location</option>
    <option value="18th Street Location">18th Street Location</option>
    <option value="Both">Both</option>
  </select>

  <div class="slidecontainer">
    <input type="range" min="0" max="16" value="0" class="slider" id="myRange">
    <p>Age: <span id="demo">All Ages</span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

On the Javascript side I have the following:

```
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");

//For the location filter
$(document).on('change', 'select', function () {
  var expr = this.val();
  var filterArticles;
  if (expr === 'Both' || expr === '') {
    filterArticles = articles;
  } else {
    //metafield array object 2 is the location object
    filterArticles = articles.filter(a => a.metafields[2].value === expr);
  }

  filterArticles.forEach((article, index) => {
    createBlock(article);
  });
});

//For the age range filter

slider.oninput = function () {

  if (slider.value == 0) {
    output.innerHTML = "All Ages";
  } else {
    output.innerHTML = this.value;
  }

  removeEvents();
  articles.forEach((article, index) => {

    //metafield object 4 is the lower value of the age range 
    //metafield object 3 is the higher value of the age range

    if (article.metafields[4].value <= slider.value && slider.value <= article.metafields[3].value) {
      createBlock(article);
      ageArticles.push(index);
    } else if (slider.value == 0) {
      createBlock(article);
    }
  })
}
```

This is what a JSON object in the array looks like:

```
{
    author: "Kevin Cadena"
    blog_id: 43130421348
    body_html: ""
    created_at: "2019-02-07T18:52:26-05:00"
    handle: "this-should-be-the-oldest-post"
    id: 16006512740
    metafields: Array(5)
    0: {id: 6030994604132, namespace: "global", key: "Event-Date", value: "1553140800", value_type: "string", …}
    1: {id: 6013532012644, namespace: "global", key: "Event-Time", value: "6:00pm-8:00pm", value_type: "string", …}
    2: {id: 6013531979876, namespace: "global", key: "Location", value: "18th Street Location", value_type: "string", …}
    3: {id: 6336530120804, namespace: "global", key: "N-AgeHigh", value: "5", value_type: "string", …}
    4: {id: 6336528711780, namespace: "global", key: "N-AgeLow", value: "2", value_type: "string", …}
    length: 5
    __proto__: Array(0)
    published_at: "2019-02-19T06:00:00-05:00"
    summary_html: ""
    tags: ""
    template_suffix: null
    title: "March 21st"
    updated_at: "2019-02-26T16:49:50-05:00"
    user_id: 26314276964
    __proto__: Object

}
```

Comment: You need help in writing the combined filter function right?

Comment: You might want to consider including the array you are trying to filter in your question.

Comment: Yes, help with writing a combined filter function. Also I included what the object in the array looks like. Including the full array would be a lot of those.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to make some changes to your code. I can't provide you with the full solution, but this will get you started

```
articles = [{age: '1', location: 'xxx'}, ...]
// first, create a copy of your articles array    
articlesCopy = ....;

// store each selected string value from the input boxes or select option onto the filterParameters object
filterParameters = {
  location: null,
  age: null
};

filterArticles() {
  const temp = this.articlesCopy.filter(article => {
    const ageMatch = article['age'].indexOf(this.filterParameters['age']) !== -1 || !this.filterParameters['location'];
    const locationMatch = article['location'].indexOf(this.filterParameters['location']) !== -1 || !this.filterParameters['age'];

    return ageMatch && locationMatch;
  });
  this.articles = temp;
}
```